# C#, MySQL, ADO.NET, delimiter causing syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, database-restore, sql-scripts

I have C# code that cycles through `.sql` files and executes what's inside them to set up a database.

One `.sql` file is basically as follows:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProc;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN
-- procedure stuff goes here
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL myProc();
```

When I input this into the MySQL Query Browser's script window, it runs perfectly... over and over again, just as one would want it to.

However, if I put the string into my `IDbCommand` and execute it...

```
connection.Open(); // An IDbConnection
IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
using (IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.CommandText = line;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
}

transaction.Commit();
connection.Close();
```

... I get the dreaded exception 1064...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE myProc() BEGIN...

So, the question is... why does MySQL let me do this with no problems, but when I try to run it from C#, it fails? And of course the second question is how I'm supposed to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this: ["Bug #46429: use DELIMITER command in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429)

Answer (score 9):

For those looking for a quick snippet...

```
var connectionString = @"server=ChangeMe;user=ChangeMe;pwd=ChangeMe;database=ChangeMe;"; 

var scriptText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\script.sql");

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var script = new MySqlScript(connection, scriptText);
    connection.Open();
    script.Execute();
}
```

Comment: For those who didnt see the obvious change.. You want to use  a `MySqlScript` instead of a `MySqlCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the commands in your script are interpreted bt the mysqlk client excutable before the SQL is sent to the server.

See [mysql commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html)

In effect all the delimiters

To interpret the script from C# you will have to write code that knows what the command is, you cannot just pass the commands line by line to the server.

e.g. you have 3 commands in that file and so want to call ExecuteNonQuery only 3 times

and from paracycle's coment you need to use the MySqlScript class